# Почему сползают блоки на телефоне, если при 320 все в порядке?

Tags: css, iphone, адаптивная-верстка

На сайте есть поп-ап, вот он (в Хроме при 320 пикселях):

[image: joxi.ru/brReML9UMjpLA1]

Вот что получаю в реальном тесте на iPhone 5s:

[image: joxi.net/823LJbBiMeklAO]

Почему так может происходить?

Comment: сделайте ширину кнопки "Продолжить" или обоих кнопок чуть меньше, посмотрите, будет ли влезать тогда.

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` есть? Если есть,  initial-scale больше 1?

Comment: Потому что в разных системах разные шрифты, разные способы сглаживания и как следствие одно и тоже слово может быть разной ширины в пикселях.